# How to get all login users sessions in Asp.Net Core 2.2?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, session-state, asp.net-core-2.2

I have site on `Asp.Net Core 2.2` using Sessions.

Is there any way to get all users sessions, and all login users and iterate them?

Also break session for some user, if he is banned.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, no. A user's authenticated state is persisted only via a local cookie on the client. There is no sort of "master list" of logged in users. However, if you like, you can create an additional table or otherwise log user logins and logouts, which you can then refer to for this information. It won't end up being totally accurate, particularly with logouts, because the user's auth could simply timeout, requiring no action that you could tie into to log that that that happened. However, if you have a known auth expiration, say 20 minutes, you can assume any login older than that time frame is no longer valid. That assumes an absolute expiration, which is the default. If there's a sliding expiration, you'll need to do even more work to keep some sort of user activity record.

Long and short, it's not trivial, but can be done if you really need the information.

As far as auto-logouts go, that merely requires invalidating the security stamp. This will effectually invalidate the user's auth cookie, forcing them to have to login again. At that point, you can check their "banned" status, however that would be done, and opt to reject their login attempt.

```
await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
```

However, that will not take effect immediately, since the security stamp is not revalidated with each request. You can make that happen by setting the validation interval to zero in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);             
});
```

However, that has a performance cost, as each request will require hitting the database to check the security stamp. You may want to set a more reasonable interval that balances wanting to logout a banned user as quickly as possible without requiring making excessive database requests.